# Thirty days hath September, April, June and November?

Tags: tenses, archaicisms, have

According to everything I can find<sup>[1](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hath),[2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hath)</sup>, and all usages I can remember ever coming across, `hath` is the 3rd person singular present tense of `have`, and not the plural.

So why does the rhyme go as follows?

> Thirty days hath September, April, June, and November

Should it not be "Thirty days *have* September, April, June, and November"?

Comment: Yes, but I believe this rhyme was written when "hath" was still commonly used.

Comment: OK, the links I posted acknowledge that hath is archaic, but they say it meant singular have, not plural. Unless you are saying there is an even more archaic meaning covering the plural as well, but I do not think this is the case.

Comment: Because it it conjugated for September only. April, June, and November are added as an addition in the manner of “Ted has a hammer... and April and June and Fred- they all have hammers.”

Comment: This poem is typically transmitted orally, so there's no authoritative punctuation, but as Jim notes, the comma after "September" is probably wrong. Maybe a dash would be better.  Or maybe a period and then an unpronounced parenthetical: "Thirty days hath September.  April, June and November [all have thirty as well]."

Comment: I suppose we're stuck with 'lyrics don't obey standard grammatical rules so often that they're generally off-topic', but I won't close-vote here as someone might have a reasonable answer. Assuming there is one (and not just 'that's the way it's always been chanted' or 'it's probably a deletion of '30 days hath September; and as for April ... well, it doth too. And then ...').

Comment: I agree with @Jim's interpretation. I may be overthinking this, but "thirty days have September, April, June and November" could suggest dividing thirty days up among the four months.

Comment: We're questioning the grammatical correctness of poems now?

Comment: It's straightforward conjunction reduction. Each of the months **has** 30 days. _30 days hath September, 30 days hath April, 30 days hath June, and 30 days hath November_ ==> _30 days hath September, April, June, and November_.

Comment: @Jim "it is conjugated for September only" - based on what? A rule of grammar or poetic license? Your example is very different, first you have swapped the order of the subject and object, and secondly you have added "- they all have hammers" to make the example grammatically correct. Are you suggesting that the rhyme once had such an addition which was then removed, but the conjugation stuck?

Comment: @Juhasz It is more usual to conjugate for the words that are there, rather than words that could be there, or otherwise there would be no point in having rules of grammar. I think Occam's razor tells us to take TaliesinMerlin's answer, which is that hath used to be plural. Unless you are suggesting that such an unprounounced parenthetical as in your example was once present and pronounced, but later omitted and the conjugation stuck.

Comment: I agree with @Jim's parse, because the way I've always heard it there's a significant pause after "September". So it's like "Thirty days hath September; April, June, and November as well."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hath** could be singular or plural in Middle English in the southern dialects.

Let's look at the first known English version of the rhyme, and discuss its form according to observed practices at the time. We go back to Harley MS 2341 (fifteenth century), as recorded in *[Secular lyrics of the XIVth and XVth centuries](https://books.google.com/books?id=bx8tAAAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=xxviij)* edited by Russell Hope Robbins (and [cross-checked with Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Days_Hath_September)):

> Thirti dayes hath nouembir,
>
> April, iune, and septembir;
>
> Of xxviij(ti) is but oon,
>
> And alle the remenaunt xxx and j.

At this point, November appears first, but even here the lyric preserves *hath*. The line breaks pose one possibility - to echo other commenters - that *November* would be read as a separate and more proximal subject to *hath*, warranting the use of the singular form.

However, this explanation is unnecessarily convoluted. Middle English verbs in plural can take an *-eth* ending, which in the case of *has* is *hath*. Here is Stephen H. A. Shepherd's instructions on Middle English in *[Middle English Romances](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/%7Ekroch/courses/lx310/handouts-09/MiddleEnglishVerb.html)* (1995; not accessible online) (cross-checked with [this course website on Middle English tenses](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/%7Ekroch/courses/lx310/handouts-09/MiddleEnglishVerb.html)):

> The present plural ending *eth* is southern, whereas the *e(n)* ending is Midland.

To use Shepherd's examples, *he loveth* or *he taketh* would have the same verb ending as *we loveth* or *we taketh* in some dialects.

The [Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED20173/track?counter=5&search_id=2589162) bears this out for *hath*, citing *hā̆th* as both a third person singular and an all-persons plural form of the verb. We are seeing plural *hath* here.

While in Early Modern English the unmarked plural replaced the *-eth* form and *have* replaced *hath*, the lyric has preserved the older verb usage across the generations.

Comment: Interesting, that "j" rhymes with "oon".  So "j" means "one" (Roman numeral) and is also pronounced "oon"

Comment: @GEdgar j was often used instead of a terminating i. This was useful for fraud prevention: if you bought a slave from someone and wrote a cheque to the tune of vij denarii, they couldn't be cheeky and change it to viii denarii later.

Comment: I feel like Christmas has come early. (No; that's irreverent.)